# How do I make wireless bridged networking work with linux guest in kvm/qemu?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am running the ubuntu 13.10 cloud image on kvm/qemu. The guest networking works fine operating in NAT mode when on wireless. Wired bridged networking (eth0 + macvtap) works fine as well. When running wireless bridged networking (wlan0 + macvtap), guest boot gets stuck at "remounted. Opts:(null)".

On the other hand, wireless bridged networking works fine with virtualbox, so I assume this is no fundamental problem which cannot be solved.

What is the missing part to get wireless bridged networking to work on kvm/qemu ?